# Why is it true that "every variable does not necessarily have a name"?

Tags: java

I have this as a T/F question on my study guide for the test with the teacher's answer as true, but can't seem to find a definitive answer as to why which I would like to know.

Comment: What does this statement even mean? If you know what your teacher means by this statement, we could perhaps help better.

Comment: The question just says "F Every variable has a name"

Comment: I'm not convinced that this should be closed, especially as off topic.

Comment: teacher #fail, challenger him/her i am sure that is what she is driving at to see how your mind works.

Answer (score 7):

This is incorrect*

Every *variable* has a name -- that which you call it.

How could one *identify* a variable without a name?

An *object* (or *value*) on the other hand, might not have a "name". Expanding on twain249's answer:

```
String[] x = { "hello" };
```

- `x` is the *name* of the variable which evaluates to the `String[]` object.
- `x[0]` evaluates to the *object* `"hello"` which does not have a "name" otherwise*

---

*Note the comment by Mat. In this *particular case* it is actually an "unnamed variable" per specification wording. This *may* have been what the teacher was referring to; ask for clarification.

Here is the JLS wording in [Types, Values and Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#10884):

> There are seven kinds of variables:
>
> [...]
>
> 3) *Array components are **unnamed variables*** that are created and initialized to default values whenever a new object that is an array is created. [...]

This definition of "unnamed variable" does not encompass expressions in general; just array components.

Comment: To be even more precise, `x` is the name of the variable which evaluates to a `String[]` *reference*, which in turn refers to a `String[]` object.

Comment: "Array components are unnamed variables" according the the JLS (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#10884) - might be a problem of terminology, but Java **does** have unnamed variables according to its spec.

Comment: Why do you doubt that this is what was meant? What is more probable: that the teacher used a word in the sense in which it was defined by the language specification or that he simply marks an answer as wrong for no particular reason.

Comment: @sepp2k Personal experience bias. I have tried to remove as such from the response.

Answer (score 3):

The teacher might be referring to Collections.

If I create an Array of Strings each of the Strings in the array doesn't have a name and is retrieved by doing array[i] where i is the index of that String.

Comment: But that's a reference to an object, it's not a variable.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I agree. But it seemed to me to be the only thing that worked, except that the teacher simply made a mistake.

Comment: wouldn't that be just arguing semantics though? As an array is not a variable but a variable can equal an array. The index position is not the variable name but the reference to the index within the variable.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth According to the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3) "*Array components* are unnamed variables".

Answer (score 2):

Every variable does have a name.

Some objects may not have a variable pointing to them, though.  For example, when you create an object like:

```
Object varName = new Object();
```

the variable `varName` is pointing to the Object in question.  But, in the case of

```
new Object();
```

the object is created but no variable points to it.

Comment: A variable is a name for a pointer to an object.  In the case of `new Object()` there is no variable at all.

Comment: Exactly! however new Object(); is not a variable than, right? however a variable as in your previous example is referencing an object.

Answer (score 0):

"Not every object is referenced by a variable" is true indeed. You can always write

```
new String("");
```

and it will create a dangling object that will be picked up by the garbage collector. Or you could create a collection of objects which are identified by the collection and an index/key.

```
Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();
v.add(1);
v.get(0); // returns Integer '1' without identifying it with a name.
```

Comment: '"Not every object is referenced by a variable" is true indeed.' Uhrm, yes, it is, but no one asked that.

Answer (score 0):

I think he's referring to anonymous classes, not variables: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm

Comment: If you suspect this, then confirm it with the OP through comments, not an answer.